# Is there some way to reform construction in ptyhon's list and dic?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

here is a list:

```py
test=[
{'name':'David','money':10},
{'name':'David','money':20},
{'name':'Scart','money':50},
]
```

I want to reform test to this:

```py
result=[
{'name':David,'money':30,'count':2},
{'name':Scart,'money':50,'count':1}
]
```

the test'length may be 500+,thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want the result to be a list? Maybe you should format the result as a dictionary. E.g. result = {'David': {'money':30, 'count':2}. Then constructing the result becomes simpler.

Comment: oh thanks,and...how to get this......(ಥ_ಥ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's you test list.

```
>>> test=[
... {'name':'David','money':10},
... {'name':'David','money':20},
... {'name':'Scart','money':50},
... ]
```

You can first build a dict mapping names to amounts of money

```
>>> amounts_by_name = {}
>>> for d in test:
...     amounts_by_name.setdefault(d['name'], []).append(d['money'])
...
```

(The `setdefault` creates the `(d[name], [])` entry if it does not exists.) The amounts are appended to the list:

```
>>> amounts_by_name
{'David': [10, 20], 'Scart': [50]}
```

Now, you can turn the dict into a list:

```
>>> [{'name': name, 'money': sum(amounts), 'count': len(amounts)} for name, amounts in amounts_by_name.items()]
[{'name': 'David', 'money': 30, 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Scart', 'money': 50, 'count': 1}]
```